# Twitter Bootstrap 2.x - close old pop-up when new one opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popup

I would like to close all opened pop-ups when a new one is opened.
I've tried like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-pop', function(){
    $('.pop-over').popover('hide');
});
```

Unfortunately this closes also the pop-up that triggers the closing action.
Any idea? Thank's!

Following the answer of Bass, I've solved my problem as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pop-up', function(){ // each pop link has `.pop-up`, but they all have different ids
    clickid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.pop-up').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id')!=clickid){ $(this).popover('hide');}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your popups the same class and a unique id. Use the function shown below:

**javascript**:

```
$(function () { 
var clickid;    
$('.popoverlink').each(function(){$(this).popover({trigger:'manual'});});
$('.popoverlink').click(function() {
        if(clickid === $(this).attr('id'))return;
        clickid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.popoverlink').each(function()
        {
                if($(this).attr('id')!=clickid){ $(this).popover('hide');}
        });

        $(this).popover('show');

    });
});
```

**html**:

```
<div class="well">  
<a href="#" class="popoverlink" id="example" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">Click for popover</a>  
</div>  

<div class="well">  
<a href="#" class="popoverlink" id="example2" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">Click for popover</a>  
</div>  

<div class="well">  
<a href="#" class="popoverlink" id="example3" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">Click for popover</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's so much, starting from your idea I've adapted it to my senario, and it works as expected. I've posted the code in my own question as here was really a mess!